# Assembly cannot compare two strings x86 linux

Tags: string, assembly, compare, character, strcmp

I am trying to re-implement strcmp in assembly.

```
.Lstrcmp:
   //check end of strings
   cmpb $0, (%rdi, %R12, 1)
   je .Lstrcmpend
   cmpb $0, (%rsi, %R12, 1)
   je .Lstrcmpend

   //compare characters
   mov (%rdi, %R12, 1), %R14
   mov (%rsi, %R12, 1), %R15
   cmp %R14, %R15
   jne .Lstrcmpend

  //go to next character
  inc %R12
  jmp .Lstrcmp

.Lstrcmpend:
   mov %R12, %rax
   ret
```

However I am unable to compare each character. 
%R12 is set to zero.

For the moment this is just a draft.

strcmp("test", "test") returns 4, with means that the first 4 characters are all equal. WORKS

strcmp("test", "test2") return 0, with means that the first character of each strings differ. I don't know why. FAIL

Does someone have an idea about what I am doing wrong ? Am I comparing each character the right way ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You load and compare 8 bytes at a time. Use byte sized operation instead. PS: learn to use a debugger so you can see what your code is doing.

Comment: How can I compare byte by byte ? Yes, will do. I struggle a bit with gdb because my assembly code is in a shared library

Comment: If you're trying to reimplement `strcmp` then 4 would not be the correct return value for `strcmp("test", "test");`. To indicate that the strings are equal you should return 0.

Comment: Use 8 bit registers such as: `mov (%rdi, %r12), %al; cmp (%rsi, %r12), %al`

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked!